# What exactly is a Critical Hit in Resident Evil 6?

Tags: resident-evil-6

There is a skill upgrade that increases chances of Critical Hits, but what are critical hits in the game? Do they provide one shot kills? How useful are they against the NPCs?

Comment: From my experience playing the game it is when you score a head shot that instantly kills a Zombie (or takes his head off, sometimes they mutate.) How this transfers to the other enemies I do not know, I would think it means increased damage.

Comment: Yeah I am wondering if I should upgrade that skill.

Answer (score 1):

[Critical Hits](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Critical_Hit) have same meaning as in previous games in RE series, and are powerful attacks that do more damage to enemy and, for some enemies, causes different animation of their death.

Note that for most weapons/enemies causing a critical hit requires hitting enemy in special spots of their body, so that will not apply to your every shot (as general gun power upgrade). They help you to conserve ammo with small enemy encounters then you have time for precise shots, but less valuable then confronting large groups of enemies. That's up to you to decide that suits you better.

Comment: How do I know the critical areas of an enemy to be shot at ?

Comment: I guess there is no any specific indication in-game of such weak spots. It's all about intuition and chance you discover it.

Comment: Well you sound knowledgable from your answer (didn't play anything after RE3).. So what's the weak spot for the J'avo ?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I had no chance to play RE6, so I can't say specifically. My personal knowledge is from playing RE5 and the wiki referenced in answer.